# BizTalk Parallel Convoy with seperate TimeOutException handling not able to build with error message "fatal error X1001: unknown system exception"

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016, biztalk-orchestrations

Consider the following basic structure of a Parallel Convoy pattern in BizTalk 2016. It is a Parallel Action with 2 active Receive shapes. Combined with a single correlation set that is being initialized by both active receives.

Now my issue arose when I want to have separate exception handling, one for the left receive, and one for the right receive. So I've put a scope around the left receive (Scope_1) with a timeout. And I've wrapped that scope in another scope (Scope_3), to catch the timeout exception.

Now for some reason this isn't allowed and I get back "fatal error X1001: unknown system exception" at build time.

[image: failing]

However, if I wrap the scope_3 around both active receives, it's building successfully:

[image]

What's the significant difference here for BizTalk to not allow separate timeout exception handling in this scenario?

By the way:

1. It doesn't matter what type of exception I'm trying to catch, or if all my scopes are a Long Running transaction or not, the occurrence of the error is the same.
2. If I make a separate correlation set for each receive, the error does not occur, but of course that's not what I want because it wouldn't make it a parallel convoy then.
3. Setting scopes to synchronized does not affect the behavior.

Comment: Does this forum post help? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e9a3ca3-4b8c-4325-8d87-e72cd12f1d8f/timeout-a-correlation-set?forum=biztalkgeneral

Comment: It describes a workaround using sequential convoy, so not really.

Answer (score 0):

First, i am able to replicate your issue.

[image]

Although visual studio reported this as an `unknown system exception` but for me it looks `unreachable code detected` based the receive shape that is inside the scope `(scope_3)` that is trying to initialize your correlation. So there's a possibility that you wont be able to initialize the correlation same way your left scope `(scope_2)` does if your main scope `(scope_1)` is having some exceptions.

The only way I can think is to use using different correlation sets, you can set your send port to follow on these correlation set.

[image]

Without using correlation sets, this should not give error during build time. For me this is considered to be an MS bug, VS should be able to point out the `unreachable code detected`, not `fatal error:`

Comment: different correlation sets means it won't be a parallel convoy anymore. But thanks for the suggestion. Your description of unreachable code sounds possible.

Comment: @r3verse, yes i agree, thus parallel convoy requires same correlation sets

Answer (score 0):

The significant difference is that the Orchestration will start up when it receives the first message, which may not be the scope_1.  So the timer would not be started in that scenario. And if it was scope_1, well it won't time out as you have received it, but it won't be timing out for scope_2.

Having the timer around both, does set the timeout in both scenarios.

What you could do is have the timeout scope as per your second example and set a flag to indicate which one was received, and use that in your exception block.

The other options is a first Receive shape that initializes the correlation set, and then a second receive after it that has the following correlation and have the timeout on that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. For your first part, I don't really understand. In both scenarios scope_1 and scope_2 have a separate timeout being set, the difference is in scope_3, which is only catching the exception. So it's still able to timeout for either 1 of them, unlike you described. As for setting flags, this is somehow impossible because it will complain about not being initialized. I've tried it in a bunch of ways, I'd challenge you to come up with a working flag scenario.

Comment: As for your final suggestion, you're describing a sequential convoy, in my case that was lucky something I could deal with so I went with that, but still it's a workaround.

Comment: The point is, how can you have a timeout on a Activate Receive shape?